# How to change defaults for a jquery DataTables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to set the defaults for the datatables I use in my project.

I can change dataTables defaults with:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults.oLanguage, {
    "sProcessing": "Loading..."
});
```

But when I try to change a default for a plugin value, like:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults.oColVis, {
    "buttonText": "Change columns"
});
```

It doesn't works.

I tried to find the defaults used by the plugin in `$.fn.dataTableExt` but couldn't find anything.

EDIT: just to be sure I made myself clear in my question, I know that I can change plugins properties in the dataTable initialization, as [Nicola Peluchetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397861/nicola-peluchetti) pointed out.

But I use the dataTable in different places in my project and I would have to repeat the code in various places that way. Not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted a reply in the DataTables forums: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11888/how-to-set-defaults-for-a-plugin . Basically you just need to alter the ColVis source at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To change the defaults of the button text you should do

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oColVis": {
            "buttonText": "Change columns"
        }
    } );
} );
```

as shown in [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/text.html) example. So basically pass the parameter in the initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is not what I want. That is only for that instance, I need it as a default for all the datatables of my project.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To change it for all instances it's done the same way except you set this parameter in the ColVis.js file rather than in your datatable init:

`code`
/**
 * Text used for the button
 *  @property buttonText
 *  @type     String
 *  @default  Show / hide columns
 */
"buttonText": "Show / hide columns",
`code`
(lines 228-234 of my ColVis.js file)